# After a GAN is trained, which parts of it are used to generate new outputs from data?

Tags: machine-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, homework

After a GAN is trained, which parts of it are used to generate new outputs from data?

Options are:

1. Neither
2. Discriminator
3. Generator
4. Both Generator and Discriminator

Comment: Is this being asked as part of coursework? If so, could you add any insight or opinion that you already have? Use [edit] to add details.

Answer (score 0):

I think so you are new to GANs.

As the name itself implies, the generator task is to generate new images to match the distribution of the model and the input data, hence it is the generator that contributes in the generation of the data, while the discriminator just tries to differentiate between the generated images by the generator and real data.